# dailyrollingfileappender in grails

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

I want to use send log messages to hourly rolling files in my grails application. Here is how I have configured log4j in `Config.groovy`

```
appenders {
    rollingFile name:"stacktrace",
                file: "/tmp/logs/app.log",
                conversionPattern: '%-5p %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m  (%F:%L)'

    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: "events",
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm",
            file: "/tmp/logs/app_events.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    )
}

root {
    error 'stacktrace'
}

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
        'org.springframework'
info  events: "com.app.events", additivity: false
```

This is how I'm getting logger for events within `com.app.events` package:

```
LOG = Logger.getLogger('events')
LOG.info("logging info")
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I don't see any logs printed. If I add `info 'events'` inside root, it works but logs from all packages also go inside `app_events.log` which is not what I want. I only want logs from `com.app.events` package to go in app_events.log.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the logging instructions line in Config.groovy are:

```
// "Logging Level" "Appender Name": "Logger Name", "Other Options"
info  events: "com.app.events", additivity: false
```

And in where you retrieve your logger:

```
// LOG = Logger.getLogger("Logger Name")
LOG = Logger.getLogger('events')
```

So to have the `events` appender receive package `com.app.events` logging, change how you retrieve your logger to:

```
LOG = Logger.getLogger('com.app.events')
```

---

Maybe using `error 'stacktrace'` in the root block is affecting log4j.  The stacktrace appender is a special appender just for full stacktraces.  Try adding another appender as your root appender and use that in place of `'stacktrace'` in your root block.

```
appenders {
    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
        name: "base",
        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm",
        file: "/tmp/logs/app_events.log",
        layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    )
}

root {
    error "base"
}
```

Comment: This didn't work either. Unless I add info into root, I dont see any logs getting app_events.log. When I add in root, I see logs from other packages also being logged into app_events.log which I want to avoid. As per the docs: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.1.2%20Logging it should not. But I'm not sure why they are getting added.

Comment: no luck. Again all logs are going into app_events.log